# choose a user of the list (loop)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

here i fetched all information of my users with a loop. as you see my table is like this:

[image]

and my code is this:

```
  <?php
$id=$fgmembersite->UserID(); 

/* echo "$id"; */


$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name= 'site';
$db_table= 'tablesite';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';


$con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die("خطا در اتصال به پايگاه داده");
$selected=mysql_select_db($db_name, $con) or die("خطا در انتخاب پايگاه داده");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET  utf8");

$dbresult=mysql_query("SELECT tablesite.name,
                              tablesite.family,
                              tablesite.username,
                              tablesite.phone_number,
                              tablesite.email
                       FROM  $db_table",$con);
   $i = 1;

                       while($amch=mysql_fetch_assoc($dbresult))

{?>
  <?php

echo "<form name=f1 id='form_$i' method='post' action='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}' accept-charset='UTF-8'>\r\n";
echo'<div dir="rtl">';
echo "نام خدمت دهنده: "."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp".$amch["name"]." ".$amch["family"]."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"."شماره تماس: ".$amch["phone_number"]."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"."ایمیل: ".$amch["email"].'<br>';
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="انتخاب مشتری"/>';echo'<hr/>';
echo'<hr/>';
echo'</div>';
echo "</form>\r\n";
    $i++;
}
?>


  <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 

}
?>
```

for each user, there is a button for choosing hem/her (for send him/her information to another page)

> this is a part of printing user's information with button for each one of them.
>   [image]

i just do not know how to choose that buddy and send selected information to another page. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a hidden input with the value of that buddy. For example (I only added the email field, but you can extend this however you need):

```
echo "<form name=f1 id='form_$i' method='post' action='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}' accept-charset='UTF-8'>\r\n";
echo'<div dir="rtl">';
echo "نام خدمت دهنده: "."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp".$amch["name"]." ".$amch["family"]."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"."شماره تماس: ".$amch["phone_number"]."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"."ایمیل: ".$amch["email"].'<br>';
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="انتخاب مشتری"/>';echo'<hr/>';
echo'<hr/>';
echo'</div>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="email" value="' . $amch["email"] . '">'; // SEND THE EMAIL ADDRESS IN THE "email" FIELD
echo "</form>\r\n";
```

Comment: how can i use this to another page? u choosed email as a unique  parameter? right?

Comment: @sajad The form method is POST so in the other page (the page that is set in the form's `action` attribute) you'll refer the the email by `$_POST["email"]`. The email itself was just example - you can add another hidden field and pass the user ID

Comment: can you help me in another question that related to this question?

Answer (score 3):

There are many solutions i think, here i present two of them.

**solution 1:**
send user id (primary key) with http POST method "you can use hidden input field" and then fetch user data from your database in the action page.

so in your loop you generate the html part like this:

```
echo "<form name=f1 id='form_$i' method='post' action='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}' accept-charset='UTF-8'>\r\n";
echo'<div dir="rtl">';
echo "نام خدمت دهنده: "."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp".$amch["name"]." ".$amch["family"]."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"."شماره تماس: ".$amch["phone_number"]."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"."ایمیل: ".$amch["email"].'<br>';
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="انتخاب مشتری"/>';echo'<hr/>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value=".$amch["id_user"]."/>';//primary key
echo'<hr/>';
echo'</div>';
echo "</form>\r\n";
```

**Solution 2:**
Do not use form to send your data and use your button as a link, therefore you can send user id (primary key) through URL (http GET method) and then fetch user data from your database in the action page.

Comment: thanks brother, i choosed the simplest way. r u persian?!

Comment: i am, and the second solution is more simple i think ;) Good Luck